# Como colocar um espaço entre dois botões?

Tags: html5, button

Tenho este código:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
    </head>
    <header>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </header>
            <body>
                  <Title>Lorem ipsum</Title></b><
                    <article>Phasellus ullamcorper turpis in vehicula dictum. Pellentesque ultrices ultrices aliquam. Sed gravida nulla elit, non commodo enim porta id. Morbi vitae mauris lacus. Integer mi ex, mollis id ornare sed, tincidunt a nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut porttitor orci. Nulla ut laoreet est. Nunc faucibus mauris libero, eget aliquet sapien suscipit eget. Praesent elementum, velit eu ullamcorper blandit, massa justo fermentum est, quis euismod neque neque non felis.</article>

                    <h3>WARNING!</h3>
                        <section> Nunc faucibus mauris libero, eget aliquet sapien suscipit eget. Praesent elementum, velit eu ullamcorper blandit, massa justo fermentum est, quis euismod neque neque non felis.</section></n>

                    <input type='button' value='Accept'> <input type='button' value='Decline'>

      </body>

</HTML>
```

---

Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa parte?

```
<input type='button' value='Accept'> <input type='button' value='Decline'>
```

Gostaria de por um pequeno espaço entre os dois.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando adiciono botões nos projetos e consequentemente irá haver a necessidade de ter outro ao lado, eu trabalho com `nth-child()` e `nth-last-child()`.

Essa "tag" do `css` consiste em dizer qual elemento filho que irá receber esse style.

Quando você quer colocar um style especifico no elemento 4 e somente nele, mas não quer adicionar mais uma class no `HTML`, você pode usar o `nth-child(4)`, e o mesmo com o `nth-last-child()`.

> ### LEMBRE-SE
>
> Você sempre terá que especificar o número do elemento dentro dos parênteses para aplicar o estilo.

Ex:

```
input{ /*-aplica por padrão a margin em todas tags input-*/
   border:none;
   background:#fafafa;
   color:000;
   margin:0 1em 0 0;
}
input:nth-child(2){ /*-irá mudar o bg e color do segundo input-*/
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
}
input:nth-last-child(1){ /*-irá retirar a margin da última tag input-*/
   margin: 0;
}
```

> **IMPORTANTE**:
>   Lembre-se de não usar tag HTML para dar espaços se você pode usar o CSS para isso, pois prolonga a estrutura prejudicando o site no ranking SEO.

Comment: Nunca soube dessas tags, eu estou começando a programar HTML/CSS então sei mais dos básicos mesmo.

Comment: @Felipe, um site que vai te ajudar bastante é esse aqui em relação ao `CSS` e um pouco de HTML também. http://www.maujor.com/

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar um espaço nos dois lados (esquerdo/direito) com `margin`:

```
button{
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```

Ao especificar apenas dois valores no `margin`, o primeiro refere-se ao *top/bottom* (cima/baixo) e o segundo a *right/left* (direita/esquerda).

O código CSS acima cria um espaço de 15 pixels à esquerda e à direita do elemento.

Caso queira adicionar o estilo *inline* no elemento, pode fazer assim:

```
         .----------.                  .----------.
<--15px--|  button  |--15px--><--15px--|  button  |--15px-->
         .----------.                  .----------.

<input style="margin: 0 15px;" type='button' value='Accept'><input style="margin: 0 15px;" type='button' value='Decline'>
```

Ou pode criar uma espaço à direita apenas no primeiro botão:

```
.----------.         .----------.
|  button  |--15px-->|  button  |
.----------.         .----------.

<input style="margin-right: 15px;" type='button' value='Accept'><input type='button' value='Decline'>
```

> Não use um `span` para fazer isso. Não é uma boa prática. Está mais pra gambiarra.

Comment: Porque  span não seria uma boa pratica?

Comment: @alxwca Porque é desnecessário você usar um elemento apenas pra criar um espaço.

Comment: Sim, eu ate entendo isso! mas com span fica mais fácil;

Comment: Isso se refere na economia de linhas não é ? Agradeço pela ajuda de vocês, deu tudo certo aqui e até o espaço foi o que eu queria. Abraços.

Comment: @alxwca Mais fácil não significa o correto e melhor. Se queres aprender a escrever código, procure fazer a coisa o mais certo possível.

Comment: @dvd em meus projetos procuro sempre as melhores praticas, mas hoje e que uso tanto framework css; mas a discussão é valida e obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: @Felipe Não é questão de economia, é fazer as coisas corretas e não usar uma coisa pra fazer outra. Uma mesa de ping-pong tb serve como mesa de jantar, mas não é mesa de jantar. Como eu disse no comentário acima, tem que procurar fazer as coisas certas.

Answer (score 0):

O **`&nbsp;`** pode ajudar você. Não criaria outro outro elemento html nem outra classe css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
    </head>
    <header>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </header>
            <body>
                  <Title>Lorem ipsum</Title></b><
                    <article>Phasellus ullamcorper turpis in vehicula dictum. Pellentesque ultrices ultrices aliquam. Sed gravida nulla elit, non commodo enim porta id. Morbi vitae mauris lacus. Integer mi ex, mollis id ornare sed, tincidunt a nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut porttitor orci. Nulla ut laoreet est. Nunc faucibus mauris libero, eget aliquet sapien suscipit eget. Praesent elementum, velit eu ullamcorper blandit, massa justo fermentum est, quis euismod neque neque non felis.</article>

                    <h3>WARNING!</h3>
                        <section> Nunc faucibus mauris libero, eget aliquet sapien suscipit eget. Praesent elementum, velit eu ullamcorper blandit, massa justo fermentum est, quis euismod neque neque non felis.</section></n>

                    <input type='button' value='Accept'>&nbsp;<input type='button' value='Decline'>
                    <br>
                    <input type='button' value='Accept'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' value='Decline'>
                    <br>
                    <input type='button' value='Accept'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' value='Decline'>

      </body>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score -2):

Uma técnica bastante utilizada, adicionar entre os inputs uma tag "span" e pelo css controlar este espaçamento;

```css
.espaco {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h3>WARNING!</h3>
  <section> Nunc faucibus mauris libero, eget aliquet sapien suscipit eget. Praesent elementum, velit eu ullamcorper blandit, massa justo fermentum est, quis euismod neque neque non felis.</section>
  </n>

  <input type='button' value='Accept'> <span class="espaco"></span><input type='button' value='Decline'>

</body>

</html>
```

Espero que lhe ajude.

Comment: Acho que não merecia esse voto contra  já que a resposta, oferece uma solução concreta, verificável e replicável.